# Compare Key names from Array with String.

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, key

I need to compare the key name from the array (eg; $domains['domainone.com']) to the variable $currentDomain, appending code if true, then outputting the key value (eg: $domains['domainone.com']['DomainOne.com']).

Basically, checking to see if the key name matches the current domain, and outputting the key value into a list. If the current domain matches the key name, it then becomes selected in the list.

```php
$currentDomain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$domains = array(
'domainone.com' => 'DomainOne.com',
'domaintwo.com' => 'DomainTwo.com',
'domainthree' => 'DomainThree.com'
);

foreach($domains as $domain) {
if($domain==$currentDomain){$selected="selected=\"selected\"";}
echo "<option value=\"http://$domain\"".$selected.">$domain</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do,

```
foreach($domains as $key => $domain) {
     if($key==$currentDomain){
        $selected="selected=\"selected\"";
     }
     echo "<option value=\"http://$key\"".$selected.">$domain</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach($domains as $key => $domain) {
    if($key==$currentDomain){
    $selected="selected=\"selected\"";}
    echo "<option value=\"http://$domain\"".$selected.">$domain</option>";
}
```

you can get a key using $key => $value

[**SEE DOCUMENTATION**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

---

**Enjoy :)**